# $\{mk~ \textrm{mod}~ N|k\in Z\}=\{k~\textrm{mod} ~N|k\in Z\}$？

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does the following equality hold?

$\{mk~ \textrm{mod}~ N|k\in Z\}=\{k~\textrm{mod}~ N|k\in Z\}$, where $(m,N)=1$.

I think so, but I do not how to prove it. I also tried a few examples, showing that it indeed holds. Can anyone give a proof?

Comment: This is equivalent to showing that for coprime integers $a,n$, we have $$ax\equiv ak\pmod n\iff x\equiv k\pmod n$$ To show this, note that if $a,n$ are coprime and $a\mid np$, then $a\mid p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the set $M := \{k \mod N \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and the map
$$f_m : M \to M, k \mapsto mk.$$
Now the image of $f_m$ is the set you have on the left, and you want to show that this is equal to $M$, i.e. that $f_m$ is surjective.
Of course you can do that directly, given an element in $M$ you can construct a preimage. But there is also an other way that might be easier: As $M$ is a finite set, the map $f_m$ is surjective if and only if it is injective. So assume that $f_m(x) = f_m(y)$ and show that we must have $x = y$.

Either way, you will most likely need the fact that there exists a $n$ such that $f_m(n) = 1$. This is due to the fact that $(m,N) = 1$, can be shown by the Euclidean algorithm and will help you to show everything else. :)

Comment: +1................Basically what is needed is the Fundamental Theorm of Arithmetic (FTA): If $C|AB$ and $\gcd (C,A)=1$ then $C|B.$ So if $f_m(k_1)=f_m(k_2)$ then $N|m(k_1-k_2)$ with $\gcd (N,m)=1,$ so $N|(k_1-k_2).$ But if $k_1\ne k_2$ then $0<|k_1-k_2|<N.$ ....But the usual way to prove  the FTA is by  applying $\exists n\; (f_m(n)=1).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I hope I'm not being too pedantic but the property you mention is not FTA. I think it's better to call it a generalization of Euclid's lemma.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas. I have seen it called FTA in books, but I have also seen introductory  books on number theory that didn't give it a name. :)